# Assigned pointer field becomes <nil>

Tags: pointers, struct, go

I have a struct:

```
type user struct {
Id string
..
data_ptr *userData
}
```

And I store slice of users in global scope:

```
type Hall struct {
    users []user
}

var hall = Hall{}    //global
```

Finally, http handler:

```
func dataHandler(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    userExist, user_ptr := hall.haveUserId()    //works fine
    switch requestType {
    case "load":    
        user_ptr.loadData()   //data loaded and user_ptr.data_ptr is set
    case "newData":
        user_ptr.data_ptr = newData  // <-- this is it, now previously set data_ptr == nil
```

So, why the heck, I mean I send "load" request, it loads data, sets `data_ptr` for `user_ptr`. But on next call, "newData" request, `user_ptr.data_ptr` is `nil`?

Just in case, here is `loadData()`:

```
func (p *user) loadData(userId) {
    ..
    data := userData {}
    p.data_ptr = &data
}
```

**EDIT:** where `user_ptr` comes from:

```
func (h *Hall) haveUserId(id string) (bool, *user) {
    for _, u := range h.users {
        if u.Id == id {
            fmt.Println("UID found")
            return true, &u
        }
    }
    return false, nil
}
```

Comment: Most likely because you operate on a _copy_ and not on the slice element. How do you create `user_ptr`?

Comment: Can you please `gofmt` and show your actual code, ie where `user_ptr` comes from?

Comment: @icza Updated, please see edit at the end of question

Comment: @user3591723, question updated with relevant piece

Comment: @DensiTensy you haven't added enough relevant information and still no `gofmt`. Just show your entire `dataHandler` function as it is actually written in your code. This can't possibly be it; there would be compile errors everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you operate on a *copy* and not on the slice element itself.

In your `haveUserId()` function the `for ... range` makes a copy of the elements it loops over, and you return the address of this copy. And so later you will modify this copy which is independent from the value in the slice. So if later you check the address in the slice element, it will still be unchanged (`nil`).

Possible fix: return the address of the slice element: `&h.users[i]`

```
func (h *Hall) haveUserId(id string) (bool, *user) {
    for i := range h.users {
        if h.users[i].Id == id {
            fmt.Println("UID found")
            return true, &h.users[i]
        }
    }
    return false, nil
}
```

To demonstrate this, see this example:

```
type Point struct{ x, y int }
ps := []Point{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
fmt.Println(ps) // Output: [{1 2} {3 4}]

for _, v := range ps {
    v.x += 10 // Modifies just the copy
}
fmt.Println(ps) // Output (unchanged): [{1 2} {3 4}]

for i := range ps {
    ps[i].x += 10 // Modifies value in slice
}
fmt.Println(ps) // Output (changed): [{11 2} {13 4}]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/4B54nwVPA9).

Comment: Many thanks, I'd never guessed this _range_ behavior differences