# Editing a struct list variable using pointer not working as expected in go

Tags: json, pointers, methods, go, struct

I have a struct that looks like

```
type Request struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Parameters []Parameter `json:"parameters"`
}
```

and

```
type Parameter struct {
    Attached bool `json:"attached"`
    Script string `json:"script"`
}
```

Now, I have unmarshalled the json into the struct, and the Script variable has an http location "http://localhost/helloworld.sh". What I am trying to do is, to change the struct variable `Parameter.Script` from `http://localhost/helloworld.sh` with the actual content of the script, which is a plain ascii shell script. I wrote a method for the inner struct like

```
func (p *Parameter) SetScript(script string)  {
    p.Script = script
}
```

using pointer to `Parameter`,

and in the `GetScript` function, try to call that method after getting the response body.

```
func GetScript(params *Request)  {
  for _, i := range params.Parameters {
    switch i.Attached {
    case false:
        client := new(http.Client)
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", i.Script, nil)
        resp, _ := client.Do(req)
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        reader, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        i.SetScript(string(reader))
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I print the struct after calling this function, it has not modified the variables, and prints the `http://localhost/helloworld.sh` only.
I am able to get the response body, which is the actual content of the script, but I am not able to replace the struct variable from within the `GetScript` function.
Could someone please point out the right way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigned pointer field becomes <nil>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760950/assigned-pointer-field-becomes-nil). Using `for _, i := range` the loop variable is a copy of the slice element, and you modify the copy, not the element in the slice. Use `for i:= range` and refer to `params.Parameters[i]`.

Comment: Thank you @icza for pointing to a similar question, but I tried that as well, as `script := string(reader); &i.Script = &script`, which threw an error saying `cannot assign to &i.Script` and nothing else.

Comment: Refresh the page, I edited my first comment.

Comment: Thank you @icza, Checking that.

Comment: Thank you @icza, that worked. If you can post it as an answer, I can accept and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `for _, i := range` loop, and you modify the loop variable inside the loop:

```
for _, i := range params.Parameters {
    switch i.Attached {
    case false:
        // ...
        i.SetScript(string(reader))
    }
}
```

The loop variable `i` is a *copy* of the slice elements you range over. So if you do any modification to it, you will only modify the *copy* and not the element in the slice. (Note that it's true that the `SetScript()` method has a pointer receiver, but it will receive the address of the *copy*, so it can and will modify only the copy.)

One workaround is use an index-only `range`, and refer to the slice element using indexing (replace all occurrence of `i` with `params.Parameters[i]`):

```
for i := range params.Parameters {
    switch params.Parameters[i].Attached {
    case false:
        // ...
        params.Parameters[i].SetScript(string(reader))
    }
}
```

You can simplify the above code by assigning the slice to a local variable (this will copy only the slice header not its elements, and it will refer to the same underlying array), and use `if` statement instead of that ugly `switch`:

```
p := params.Parameters
for i := range p {
    if !p[i].Attached {
        // ...
        p[i].SetScript(string(reader))
    }
}
```

An alternative simplification / improvement is to take the address of the index expression, and use that (so you can omit repeating it multiple times):

```
for i := range params.Parameters {
    p := &params.Parameters[i]
    if !p.Attached {
        // ...
        p.SetScript(string(reader))
    }
}
```