# Strange golang "append" behavior (overwriting values in slice)

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, append, slice

I have this simple code:

```
import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    val int
}

func main() {
    var a = make([]*Foo, 1)
    a[0] = &Foo{0}

    var b = [3]Foo{Foo{1}, Foo{2}, Foo{3}}
    for _, e := range b {
        a = append(a, &e)
    }

    for _, e := range a {
        fmt.Printf("%v ", *e)
    }
}
```

I was expecting it to print `{0} {1} {2} {3}`, however it prints `{0} {3} {3} {3}`. What happened here?

Comment: Playground of this at https://play.golang.org/p/nftYWXrflD

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because in the `for` loop you operate with a *copy* and not with the slice/array element itself.

The `for ... range` makes a copy of the elements it loops over, and you append the address of this temporary, loop variable - which is the same in all iterations. So you add the same pointer 3 times. And this temporary variable will be set to `Foo{3}` in the last iteration (last element of the array), so that's why you see that printed 3 times.

Fix: do not add the address of the loop variable, but the address of the array element:

```
for i := range b {
    a = append(a, &b[i])
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7A3H9-gcIy)):

```
{0} {1} {2} {3}
```

See possible duplicate [Assigned pointer field becomes <nil>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760950/assigned-pointer-field-becomes-nil).

#### Reasoning for this behavior

In Go there are *pointer* types and *non-pointer* types, but no ["references"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_type) (in the meaning it is used in C++ and Java). Given the fact that there are no "reference" types in Go, this is not an unexpected behavior. The loop variable is just an "ordinary" local variable, it can only hold a value (which may be a pointer or non-pointer), but not a reference.

Excerpt from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35426997/1705598):

> Pointers are values just like let's say `int` numbers. The difference is the interpretation of that value: pointers are interpreted as memory addresses, and `int`s are interpreted as integer numbers.
>
> When you want to change the value of a variable of type `int`, you pass a pointer to that `int` which is of type `*int`, and you modify the pointed object: `*i = newvalue` (the value assigned is an `int`).
>
> Same goes with pointers: when you want to change the value of a variable of pointer type `*int`, you pass a pointer to that `*int` which is of type `**int` and you modify the pointed object: `*i = &newvalue` (the value assigned is an `*int`).

All in all, the loop variable is just a normal variable having the element type of the array/slice you're looping over, and for it to have the value of the actual iteration, the value must be assigned to it which copies the value. It is overwritten in the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! this behavior is very confusing though. Not sure why they design it like this...

Comment: The reasoning makes sense, it's definitely confusing to a go newcomer. I spent a long time trying to figure out what was wrong, I thought it might be a race condition and it took me a while to even find this answer because I wasn't sure what I was even looking for.

Comment: To help visualize the problem, here's an output from `fmt.Println(a)` after the loop in the OP's code finishes: `[0xc0000160d0 0xc0000160d8 0xc0000160d8 0xc0000160d8]`

Answer (score 3):

On each iteration of your loop, the value of `e` changes, yet each time you're passing a pointer to `e` into the slice. So you end up with a slice containing 3 pointers to the same value.

You can also make a copy of the value and pass its pointer. Since on each iteration, you're making a new copy of the value, the pointers passed to the slice will point to different values:

```
var a = make([]*Foo, 1)
a[0] = &Foo{0}

var b = [3]Foo{Foo{1}, Foo{2}, Foo{3}}
for _, e := range b {
    eCopy := e
    a = append(a, &eCopy)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/VKLvNePU9af

Answer (score 1):

Because you are appending the slice using as a pointer reference actually you are not creating new entries in the slice but updating every time the last entry. Changing the code from pointer reference to normal value reference it will work.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    val int
}

func main() {
    var a = make([]Foo, 1)
    a[0] = Foo{0}

    var b = [3]Foo{Foo{1}, Foo{2}, Foo{3}}
    for _, e := range b {
        a = append(a, e)
    }

    for i, e := range a {
        fmt.Printf("%d: %v\n", i, e)
    }
}
```

Working code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dop73cEHCM).